# Julia, strange behaviour when changing keys while iterating through dictionary

Tags: dictionary, iterator, julia

I experienced a (in my opinion) strange behaviour while iterating through a Julia Dictionary and chaning key names during the iteration.
The following example works as expected:

```
a = Dict("klaus_one" => 3,
         "bernd_one" => 5,
         "gabi_one" => 8)

for i= keys(a)
     x = pop!(a,i)
     a[join([i,"new"],"_")] = x + 3
end
```

Returns (as expected)

```
# Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 3 entries:
#   "gabi_one_new"  => 11
#   "bernd_one_new" => 8
#   "klaus_one_new" => 6
```

However:

```
a = Dict("klaus_one" => 3,
         "bernd_one" => 5,
         "gabi_one" => 8)

for i=1:5

    if i!=1

        # _keys = deepcopy(keys(a))
        _keys = keys(a)
        for k = _keys
            k_base = join(split(k,"_")[1:2],"_")
            a[k_base] = pop!(a,k) + 3 
        end
    end
    # _keys = deepcopy(keys(a))
     _keys = keys(a)

    for k = _keys
        k_new = join([k,"new2"],"_")
        a[k_new] = pop!(a,k) 
    end
end
```

Results in:

```
# Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 3 entries:
#   "klaus_one_new2"      => 27
#   "gabi_one_new2"       => 32
#   "bernd_one_new2_new2" => 17
```

As the values and the key "bernd_one_new2_new2" show, more than three iterations take place (although the dictionary is of length 3). However the "strange" behaviour can be cured by deepcopying the keys into a new object.

Is is behaviour as expected ?

Thanks in advance !

(btw. I am using Julia Version 0.4.6 (2016-06-19 17:16 UTC))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected: you cannot safely iterate through a dictionary while mutating it. This is a common restriction in other languages as well: some of them prevent you from doing so; others allow it but exhibit similar behavior.

Comment: It's an unfortunate problem: it's hard to check for without wrecking performance, and it's nearly impossible to make this safe.

Comment: If wastage of a bit of time and memory is ok, iterating over `collect(keys(a))` instead of `keys(a)` should produce the expected results.

Comment: Thank's Dan! collect does not seem to affect the performance very much: time ratio (collect/vs iterator) = 0.72, "number of iteration" ratio (collect / vs iterator) = 0.62 (although the comparison is a little bit useless since using the iterator generates wrong results :) )